# Escape $ to \\$ with Javascript replace regular expression

Tags: javascript

I have a string of `"aa$bb$cc"`; and I want to replace it to be `"aa\$bb\$cc"`
I've tried this:

```
var str = "aa$bb$cc"
str.replace(/$/g, "\\$");
```

But the outpus is `"aa$bb$cc\$"`

How can I replace it and get same (*correct...*) result in all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = str.replace(/\$/g, "\\$");
```

`$` in a regular expression means "end of the line". Therefore, it's replacing all the ends of lines with `\$`. Escape the `$` in the regular expression and it works.

Comment: I tried to escape it with `str.replace(\\$/g, "\\$");` Damn! I tried it for half an hour until I gave up!

Answer (score 3):

Your regex should escape the `$` as well.

```
/\$/g
```

This is because it's a special character that denotes the end of the string *(or end of the line if the `m` modifier is used)*.

Comment: I tried to escape it with str.replace(\\$/g, "\\$"); Damn! I tried it for half an hour until I gave up!

Comment: @gdoron: Ah, yeah the regex literal doesn't swallow the escape character like a string literal.

Comment: "Curse them! We hates them!" (Lord of the rings...)

Answer (score 1):

`$` has a special meaning in a regex, it achors to the end of the string. `^` anchors to the start of the string. Try escaping it `/\$/g`

You are basically saying "replace the end of the line with '\$'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `"aa$bb$cc".replace(/\$/g, "\\$");`